# Discord.js setTimeout in for-loop is printing the values at the same time , is there any way to make this simple program work

Tags: javascript, for-loop, discord.js, settimeout

My code is :

```js
for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
  delay(i);
}

function delay(i) {
  setTimeout(() => console.log(`${i} is the number`), 2000);
}
```

The output i am getting after 2 second is :

0 is the number

1 is the number

2 is the number

3 is the number

4 is the number

5 is the number

They all print together immediately after 2 second , while I want each of them to print after 2 second for eg :

0 is the number

(after 2 second)

1 is the number

(after 2 second)

2 is the number .....

Is there any way to make it work?
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` is a non-blocking function. The `for` loop doesn't wait for `delay` to be finished, but just calls `delay(i)` six times in a row directly.

To make this case work, you could use `async/await` and Promise-ify `setTimeout`:

```js
(async () => {
for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    await delay(i);
}
})();

function delay(i) {
return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(`${i} is the number`);
    resolve();
}, 2000));
}
```